# Spring Thymeleaf form validation being ignored

Tags: forms, spring-boot, validation, thymeleaf

I have a Spring MVC application with a thymeleaf form which I am trying to validate, though the validations are being ignored (basic example, I insert no data into the form and click straight away "submit").

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public String getTest(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("emailContatti", new EmailContatti());
    return "test";
}

@PostMapping("/test/validation")
public String testInputValidation(@Valid @ModelAttribute("emailContatti") EmailContatti emailContatti, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) return "contatti";
    else return "email-inviata";
}
```

**POJO**

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EmailContatti {

@NotBlank(message = "campo obbligatorio")
private String nome;

@NotBlank(message = "campo obbligatorio")
private String cognome;

@NotBlank(message = "campo obbligatorio")
@Email(message = "formato email invalido")
private String email;

@NotBlank(message = "campo obbligatorio")
@Size(min = 10, max = 13, message = "numero di telefono invalido")
private String telefono;

@NotBlank(message = "campo obbligatorio")
private String messaggio;
```

}

**Thymleaf form**

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/test/validation}" th:object="${emailContatti}" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Nome:</td>
        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{nome}" /></td>
        <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('nome')}" th:errors="*{nome}">Name Error</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cognome:</td>
        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{cognome}" /></td>
        <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('cognome')}" th:errors="*{cognome}">Cognome Error</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td><input type="email" th:field="*{email}" /></td>
        <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}">Email Error</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Numero telefono:</td>
        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{telefono}" /></td>
        <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('telefono')}" th:errors="*{telefono}">telefono Error</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Messaggio:</td>
        <td><input type="text" th:field="*{messaggio}" /></td>
        <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('messaggio')}" th:errors="*{messaggio}">messaggio Error</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So as you can see I made sure to add the model attribute in the controller, I made sure to insert the BindingResult after the @Valid annotation.

**The result**

The form gets displayed, the code runs without issues, though the validations are totally ignored and the "success" (invia-email) page is shown.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your time and experience

===========EDIT============

By adding a breakpoint at bindingResult.hasErrors() I saw that it returns false.
I have also tried using different annotation validations such as @NotNull @NotEmpty but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Your if else block is wrong, change your code like below:

```
@PostMapping("/test/validation")
public String testInputValidation(@Valid @ModelAttribute("emailContatti") EmailContatti emailContatti, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "contatti";
    }
    return "email-inviata";
}
```

Comment: If you are referring to the fact that it doesn't have curly braces, for single statement conditions it's fine. Also, with the debugger I saw that .hasErrors() returns false, that's where the problem I believe is, though I don't know why